# Deleting and Re-Adding Nodes in C++

Tags: c++

I'm using a linked list to implement a concordance program. If the same word is read multiple times, I need to delete the current node, increment the count, and add a new node. I can't add any more functions to this program. I'm thinking I'll have to use get_count somehow, but I'm not sure.

For example, instead of it looking like this:

THE 1
THE 1

It should be:

THE 2

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Header file:

```
#ifndef CONCORDANCE_H
#define CONCORDANCE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

const int MAX = 8;

class Concordance
{
    public:
        typedef char Word[MAX+1];

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        Concordance()
        {
            first = NULL;
        }

        // DESTRUCTOR
        ~Concordance();

        // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        void insert(Word& word, int& n);
        void remove(Word& word);
        int get_count(Word& word);

        // OTHER FUNCTIONS
        int length() const;
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out_s, Concordance& c); 

    private:
        // NODE STRUCT
        struct Node
        {
            Word wd;
            int count;
            Node *next;
        };
        Node *first;    

        // GET_NODE FUNCTION
        Node* get_node(Word& word, int& count, Node* link);   
};

#endif
```

Class:

```
//class definition
#include "concordance.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

Concordance::~Concordance()
{
    Node *temp;
    while(first != NULL)
    {
        temp = first;
        first = first -> next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void Concordance::insert(Word& word, int& n)
{
    Node *prev;

    if(first == NULL || strcmp(first -> wd, word) > 0)
        first = get_node(word, n, first);
    else
    {
        prev = first;

        while(prev -> next != NULL && strcmp(prev -> next -> wd, word) < 0)
            prev = prev -> next;

        prev -> next = get_node(word, n, prev -> next);
    }
}

void Concordance::remove(Word& word)
{
    Node *prev, *temp;
    prev = temp;

    if(prev -> wd == word)
    {
        first = first -> next;
        delete prev;
    }

    else
    {
        while(strcmp(prev -> next -> wd, word) > 0)
        prev = prev -> next;
        temp = prev -> next;
        prev -> next = temp -> next;
        delete temp;
    }

}

int Concordance::get_count(Word& word)
{
    while(strcmp(first -> wd, word) != 0)
        first = first -> next;

    return first -> count;
}

int Concordance::length() const
{
    Node *cursor;
    int length;

    length = 0;
    for(cursor = first; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor -> next )
      length++;
    return length;
}

Concordance::Node* Concordance::get_node (Word& word, int& count, Node* link)
{
    Node *temp;

    temp = new Node;
    strcpy(temp-> wd, word);
    temp-> next = link;
    temp -> count = count+1;
    return temp;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out_s, Concordance& c)
{
    Concordance::Node *output;

    out_s << "Word" << setw(10) << " " << "Count" << setw(8) << endl;
    out_s << "--------------------" << endl;

    for(output = c.first; output != NULL && output->next != NULL; output = output-> next )
        out_s << left << setw(10) << output-> wd << right << setw(9) << output -> count << endl;

    if(output != NULL)
        out_s << output-> wd << setw(13) << " " << output -> count << endl;
    out_s << "--------------------" << endl;

    return out_s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to search your list for the existing word, and if it's found, simply increment the count in the existing node structure:

```
Node* existing = first;
while (strcmp(existing->wd, word) != 0)
    existing = existing->next;
if (existing)
    ++existing->count;
else
{
    // not already existing, so add new node
}
```

But if you're allowed to, I would strongly suggest using a `std::map` instead - because then practically everything is handled for you:

```
std::map<std::string, int> mapWords;
// for each word:
++mapWords[word];
```

These two lines of code can replace practically all of your linked list code, and an additional benefit is the lookups will be much quicker since maps use a binary tree rather than a linked-list which must be searched linearly.

If you have a C++11 compiler you can also use `unordered_map` which uses hash tables and can be even faster since the elements in the map are not kept sorted.

Comment: Doesn't std::map use a binary tree? std::unordered_map is the one that uses a hash table, I believe.

Comment: @KevinCadieux: Yes, good point (although I think that might be implementation defined though? Dunno.) `unordered_map` is c++11 only I believe so the OP may not be able to use this, I will update the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thank you! I tried putting the code you suggested at the top of the `insert` function. It compiled, but I get a Segmentation fault: 11 error when running the program. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mitchell: My code example doesn't handle the case where `first` is NULL, you will need to account for this.